# (uiautomator) apache poi lib is in the classpath, but "error: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist" happens

Tags: java, excel, apache, android-uiautomator

I have Uiautomator project, that run some tests, I got some problems with adding poi lib.

I'm using Idea - I have Poi-3.10 in libraries and in the Modules/dependencies dirrectly.
When I put it to the lib folder, where uiautomator.jar is, I got

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
```

And also I have it in the artifact build path as an extracted .jar (like uiautomator.jar).

Any suggestions?